# MVC3 - How to add dropdown to a form (Post) populated with different entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I am working in a `MVC 3` application. I have a Create Form with following code.

```
@model Xrm.Student
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create Student Record";
 }
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Student", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => @Model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">                                      
         @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.FirstName)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.FirstName)
    </div>
<div>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
}
```

I want to add a new drop down under Firsname field which should be populated with pubjects.  Subject is different Entity. I could be very easy, but I am newbie with MVC so I just stuck here. Can anyone please suggest me the way to achieve it.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: see my tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc
  [2]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Subject")]
    [Required]
    public string SubjectId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller populate and pass this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Student = new Student();
    model.Subjects = db.Subjects;
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally have your view strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Student Record";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Student.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">                                      
         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Student.FirstName)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Student.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SubjectId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">                                      
         @Html.DropDownListFor(
             x => x.SubjectId, 
             new SelectList(Model.Subjects, "Id", "Name"),
             "-- Subject --"
         )
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SubjectId)
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
}
```

The `"Id"` and `"Name"` values I used for the SelectList must obviously be existing properties on your `Subject` class that you want to be used as respectively binding the id and the text of each option of the dropdown.

Comment: Right answer, the only thing I would change is to move the collection of subjects into the ViewBag as I think they do not belong to the model itself (like a countrylist for an address model etc..). But that's just a matter of personal taste, apart from that it's all good !

Comment: @GiorgioMinardi, I agree with you, they don't belong to the model. They belong to the **view model**. That's why I added them to the view model => because the view model represents the requirements of the view and in this view we have a requirement to display a dropdown of subjects. I wouldn't use ViewBag. It's weakly typed. Personally I prefer to use a view model.

Comment: @Darin, I was intending the viewmodel. Btw as I said it's only a matter of taste, I usually assign to the viewmodel only the info that belong to it (the student viewmodel in my opinion should not include a list of subject, but this is arguable), and assign the rest to the ViewBag. One reason can be that I want to reuse the StudentViewModel somewhere else and I don't want to show the list of availables subjects.

Comment: Darin has the right answer again, but on one small issue I agree with @GiorgioMinardi - it's fine to use the ViewBag for the  collection of subjects.

Comment: No, it's not fine (for me) and nobody on this planet will ever convince me the contrary nor I will ever use it in my codebase.

Comment: " and nobody on this planet will ever convince me the contrary"  
I think @GiorgioMinardi was just posting another solution: he was not trying to force anyone to use his solution.In this case even for me is not a problem using the viewbag for the collection of the subjects.
(I don't want to convince no one)